# Ruby metaprogramming to generate ActiveRecord associations on a given model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems, metaprogramming

I'm extracting part of my app into a Gem, which involves creating some new ActiveRecord models.  At the moment these models look something like this:

```
Class Wordcount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword
  belongs_to :article
end

Class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wordcounts
  has_many :articles, :through => :wordcounts
end
```

The gem will hook into any ActiveRecord model with String or Text fields, not just my defined `Article` model in the existing Rails app this code comes from.

What do I need to do in order to generate the relevant AR associations based on whichever model the gem's functionality is being applied to?  I'm hoping to end up with:

```
has_my_gem_functionality :on => [:field1, :field2, ...]
```

And for the rest to be safely encapsulated within the gem.

I'm assuming I'll also have to metaprogram the Migrations as well.  I think what I'm trying to do is relatively simple, it's just slightly too far out of my comfort zone.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what migrations might be needed for this gem to function?

Comment: So the migrations would for the most part act indepedently: adding columns to the `wordcounts` and `keywords` tables.  They will also need foreign keys for the tables they are hooking into, namely `:article` at present.  I'm actually not certain about this, sorry: when you have a `belongs_to` or a `has_many` association, which tables (or both?) need foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the source, luke! :)**

Just take a look at the source of some other gems that do similar things. For example:

- [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/) *(includes a migration)*
- [activerecord-embedding](https://github.com/iblue/activerecord-embedding) *(a very small gem that does some associations)*

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had a look at a few other gems but just got confused; these examples are a little clearer.

So if I understand correctly, I need to do `class_eval do ;end`, and use that to add methods to the class.  I'll look into that method more now.